# pandas merge df and series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a large dataframe with series. I hear join/merge is the fastest way. I want to filter the index of the dataframe using the values(not the index) from the series. here are my codes and errors

```
pd.merge(df_customer, interested_customers, left_index=True, how='inner')
```

error:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Here is the join function:

```
df_customer.join(interested_customers, how='inner', left_index=True)
```

Here is the error:
`join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'left_index'`

If i take away the left_index i get an empty dataframe. Eventhough they are matching values

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: 2 notes:
1. I wanted to use join for speed
2. the index typed mistmatched, when i converted them to int it worked.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have `customer` as an index in the `df_customer` DF:

```
df_customer.loc[interested_customers]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(df_customer, pd.DataFrame(interested_customers, columns = ['name_of_merging_column']), left_index=True, how='inner')
```

OR

```
df_customer.join(interested_customers.astype(int), how='inner', left_index=True)
```

OR

```
df_customer[df_customer.index.isin([interested_customers])]
```

Comment: isin is too slow